# Max number of cells which can be updated using setValues()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my script I am trying to update a large number of cells in a single iteration using the setValues() function but I get the "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]" error. When I reduce the size of the array the cells are updated with no problem. I can't find any information on the limitations of the setValues() function so is the size of the array really an issue?

I really don't want to have to split my array up so is there anyway around this error using the full array?

```js
function counter(parts, milestones, WIPSheet, MSSheet, magnets) {
    
  var MSSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(''); 
  var WIP = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  
  var MSSOI = MSSS.getSheetByName(MSSheet); 
  var WIPSOI = WIP.getSheetByName(WIPSheet);
  
  var location = 0;
  
  var ms = '';
  
  var WIPparts = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < magnets.length; i++){
    
    if(magnets[i][3] == 0){
     
    ms = magnets[i][1]  
    
    for(var j = 1; j < milestones.length +1; j++){
          
      if(ms == milestones[j-1][0] ){
        for(var l = 0; l < j; l++){
          for(var k = 0; k< parts.length; k++){
        
        parts[k][2] += milestones[l][k+1]; } }}
      
    }
      
     for( j = 0; j < parts.length; j++){
     
     WIPparts[parts[j][1]-3] = [];
     WIPparts[parts[j][1]-3][0] = parts[j][2];
     
    } 
     
 
     WIPSOI.getRange(3,magnets[i][2],WIPparts.length,1).setValues(WIPparts);
 
     for( var k = 0; k<parts.length; k++){
     
      parts[k][2] = 0;
      
    }  
      
    }
   
  }
  
}
```

The array itself is two dimensional and actually currently contains 175 numbers eg [[1],[2],[3],...,[175]]

Comment: I'd have to see the full array to check if it is the problem or the sheet, how long is it? Can you share the code?

Comment: I just updated the Code @Kriggs. The array itself is nothing special just a 2D array with 175 entries. If I reduce the size of the array the code works fine

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your array, I update thousands of cells at once without a hiccup, maybe there's an empty array somewhere, update

```
WIPSOI.getRange(3,magnets[i][2],WIPparts.length,1).setValues(WIPparts);
```

with

```
for( lin in WIPparts )
  for( col in WIPparts[ lin ] )
    if( !WIPparts[ lin ][ col ] )
      WIPparts[ lin ][ col ] = "";


WIPSOI.getRange(3,magnets[i][2],WIPparts.length,WIPparts[0].length).setValues(WIPparts);
```

The first part will eliminate non-initialized arrays, and the second part will eliminate the chance of getting the legnth of the range wrong.

Comment: thank you, I will try this but I am confused as to why my code would work for a smaller array. Additionally, when I have the debugging window open the array in question appears to be populated normally. Maybe I need to look closer at the elements.

Comment: Yeah @Kriggs unfortunately that didn't fix the problem, I still receive the error about converting from array to object. In the debugging window all of the arrays are initialized. It seem as though  the max size of the array that my program will work with is 84 elements.

Comment: The array It self is populated based on a look up table and the values are just simple values here's the best I can do: http://tny.cz/83bd96c5

Comment: Likely an error somewhere else. Ive updated thousands of cells before using a single array